# Read employee number and salary (exercise to use static keyword)

Tags: java, beginner, static

WAP to create a class called Employee having empid and salary as data members and salary as data members. Create objects of this class and count no. of employees working in an organization using static keyword.

This is my solution for the above question. Is it correct way of doing this? I am a beginner so I would appreciate your help. Let me know of my mistakes.

```
    import java.util.*;
    class Employee{
private int empid;
private int salary;
private static int count;

private void setValue(int empid,int salary){
this.empid=empid;
this.salary=salary;
count++;
}

private void getValue(){
System.out.println("EmpId = "+empid);
System.out.println("Salary ="+salary);
System.out.println("Number of employees: = "+count);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    Employee e=new Employee();
    int id,sal;
    System.out.println("Enter Employee Id: ");
    id=kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Salary: ");
    sal=kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The Values entered are :");
    e.setValue(id,sal);
    e.getValue(); 
    Employee e1=new Employee();
    System.out.println("Enter Employee Id: ");
    id=kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Salary: ");
    sal=kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The Values entered are :");
    e1.setValue(id,sal);
    e1.getValue();
}}
```

Comment: Downvoted because you really should be able to understand how classes work (e.i. how to use a constructor, how to use the most basic methods, ...). Still answered because I do want you to actually learn how to do it correctly.

Comment: I have made changes according to your answer(in the question itself). Please review it once. I hope now its fine.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Imus Seems a bit harsh to downvote because someone's a beginner, and doesn't know everything about programming yet. It took me a couple of years till I could use classes.

Comment: @Heslacher Thanks for your suggestion. I will remove the answer from my question and I am new to StackExchange so I didn't know that.

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi I already rolled back that edit.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Hmm, you're right. My initial thought was that the "code does not work as intended" which would be against the rules of this site. But the way he only used the setter once it technically did work. I found flagging this question too harsh as well so went with a downvote instead. Thinking back about it now that might not be the right thing either. Removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You use a setter to modify an existing employee. But it makes no sense to change the id and salary together. In fact, you should never change the id of an employee.

This should be the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) of the class instead. In your main I would expect to see the folowing flow:

```
Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
int id,sal;
System.out.println("Enter Employee Id: ");
id=kb.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Salary: ");
sal=kb.nextInt();
System.out.println("The Values entered are :");
Employee e=new Employee(id, sal);
```

A second thing to note is that a method with prefix "get" is expected to return some value of the object. Either rename that `getValue()` method to something like `printInfo()` or provide actual getters:

```
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public static int getNbOfEmployees(){
    return count;
}
```

These can then be used somewhere else to print out the info, for example in your main:

```
System.out.println("EmpId = " + e.getId());
System.out.println("Salary =" + e.alary());
System.out.println("Number of employees: = " + Employee.getNbOfEmployees());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following changes according to @Imus. For multiple employees, I think using an array of object references would be great.

```
    class Employee{
private int empid;
private int salary;
private static int count;

Employee(int empid,int salary){
this.empid=empid;
this.salary=salary;
count++;
}

public int getId(){
return empid;
}

public int getSalary(){
return salary;
}

public static int getNumberOfEmployees(){
return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    int id,sal;
    System.out.println("Enter Employee Id: ");
    id=kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Salary: ");
    sal=kb.nextInt();
    Employee e=new Employee(id,sal);
    System.out.println("The values are :");
    System.out.println("EmpId = "+e.getId());
    System.out.println("Salary = "+e.getSalary());
    System.out.println("No. of employees = "+Employee.getNumberOfEmployees());

}
}
```